# How to implement ssl certificate in C# webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, restsharp

We have written an .exe webservice serving rest requests (using restsharp nuget package). Now we need to secure it with an ssl certificate and we dont know where to start or find something useful googling... if anyone can point me in the right direction i would appreciate it

Comment: SSL certificates are bound to your domain, maybe try looking into lets encrypt?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got your question right as restsharp seems to be a client library. But In any case your service can't handle SSL itself you could reverse proxy it with something like NGIX.